# Send dynamic Grails g:select values to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, grails

I need help trying to get the values from a g:select statement and passing them into a JavaScript function.

So far I have the button

```
 <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='runReport("${reportInstance.name}")'>Run Report</a>
```

Which calls a .js file with

```
function runReport(reportIn){
var url = reportViewerPath + reportDirectory + reportIn + reportSuffix + promptChain;
window.open(url,'Report Viewer','fullscreen=yes,menubar=yes,status=yes');
}
```

And this works great. Now the challenge is we have g:select statements on the main .gsp page, but they are variable in number. There could none, or there could be 20, it just depends on the report chosen by the end user.

```
<g:select id="${prompt.name}" from="${listPromptValues[prompt.name]*.values().collect()}" name="prompt" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
```

This generates the drop down menu with the values for what ever prompt there is.

How do I grab ${prompt.name} and the selected value for every prompt on the page, and then pass that to the .js file as well?

Ideally when runReport() is called, it will pass the reportName, and  the prompts will get passed as

```
&Phone=867-5309&City=NewYork&Name=Jenny
```

Each url variable would be an optional g:select, so it could also be

```
&City=NewYork&Name=Jenny
```

I feel like something like this [Related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904066/retrieving-gselect-value-from-within-gsp-no-form?rq=1) would be on the right track.

```
var prompts = "";
$('$prompt.name').change(function() {

    prompts += $(this).text();
    $("a").attr('href', function(i, h) {
        return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&" : "?") + "selectValue="+val;

    });
});
```

However prompts would have to be a global so that it isn't overwritten every time there is a change.

Edit: Here is the DOM object on the .gsp page

```
<div id="runButton">
    <g:form controller="report">
        <g:if test="${reportInstance?.id}">
            <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='runReport("${reportInstance.name}")'>Run Report</a>
        </g:if>
    </g:form>
 </div>

<ol class="property-list report">
    <g:if test="${reportInstance?.prompts}">
    <hr>
    <li class="fieldcontain" id="prompt">
        <g:each var="prompt" in="${reportInstance.prompts}">
                <span id="prompts-label" class="property-label">
                    <g:message code="report.prompts.label" default="${prompt.description}:" />
                </span>
                <g:if test="${prompt.datatype.type == 'DropDown'}">
                    <g:select id="${prompt.name}" from="${listPromptValues[prompt.name]*.values().collect()}" name="prompt" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
                  <br>                            
              </g:if>
          </g:each>
        </li>
    </g:if>
</ol>
```

And then in run.js

```
function runReport(reportIn){
    var promptChain = $("#prompt :select[name=prompt]").serialize();
    reportName = reportIn;
    ...
}
```

Am I going about this incorrectly?

Edit 2: Grabbing the prompts like it should

```
...
<g:if test="${prompt.datatype.type == 'DropDown'}">
    <g:select id="${prompt.name}" from="${listPromptValues[prompt.name]*.values().collect()}" name="${prompt.name }" value="" noSelection="['':'']"/>
    <br>                            
</g:if>
...
```

and the jQuery

```
var promptChain = jQuery('select').serialize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so just serialize the form's select elements.  Doesn't matter how many their are.  No need to track some global variable.

```
function runReport(reportIn) {
   var promptChain = $("select[name=prompt]").serialize();
   ....
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8LR/)

Comment: The select isn't in a form, its just listed in a ordered list? Or would it be easier to wrap them in a form tag?

Comment: Ok, so replace the #myForm with the id of your UL?

Comment: When I add it, I'm getting an "Uncausght TypeError: Cannot call method 'serialize' of null" in the developer console in Chrome.

Comment: Looks to be semi working. Any idea how i would replace name=prompt with the id from the <g:select >?

Comment: Why don't you just make the name the same as the ID.  And adjust the jquery selector to use a class instead of the name attribute?

Comment: Awesome! I got it grabbing the correct names. Now I just need some regex to grab the correct chuck of the prompt and all will be well again. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you need REGEX.  Also, updating your question asking if the answer I've provided is the right approach feels rude.  Either my question helped you or it didn't.

Comment: I wasn't asking if what you did was right. No need to get offended.

Comment: As to why I believe I need to use REGEX. The prompt values that are getting serialized look like
Term=%5B201350%2C+Summer+Session+2013%5D
The only part of that that I need to pass on in the URL would be Term=201350, stripping out all the unneeded characters. I suppose a substring could also work.